# Для каких целей необходим приоритет процесса?

Tags: linux

Например команда

```
renice 10 -p <PID>
```

Что она делает? Приоритет чего она подняла с 0 до 10? Ман читал, но чет не понял.

UPD: Я правильно понимаю, что чем выше приоритет, тем меньше памяти потребляет процесс?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значение *уступчивости* или *любезности* (*nice*, *niceness*) — это концепция приоритета процесса в UNIX-подобных ОС. Оно определяет, насколько данный конкретный процесс *любезен* по отношению к остальным и готов уступить им *процессорное время* т.е. оно противоположно понятию *приоритет*.

Чем больше *приоритет* процесса, тем больше шанс, что данный процесс получит квант времени (а статистически говоря быстрее выполнится полностью), когда одновременно несколько процессов конкурируют за процессор, т.е. работают одновременно. Это далеко не единственный параметр, влияющий на работу планировщика  (например процессы `root`'а имеют больший приоритет априори), но основной доступный пользователю напрямую.

Диапазон значений в современном Linux составляет от `-20` (наименьшая уступчивость и наибольший приоритет) до `19` (соответственно наоборот, наибольшая уступчивость и наименьший приоритет); причём изменения на `1` пункт примерно соответствует уменьшению шанса занять ЦП в `1.25` раз (см. [`man 7 sched`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html), раздел *The nice value*).

Само собой, обычный пользователь может изменять значения приоритетов только своих процессов, а для установки *уступчивости* ниже определённого уровня (значения `$(( 40 - $(ulimit -e) ))`, по умолчанию 0; задаётся в `/etc/security/limits.conf`) процесс должен обладать [мандатом](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) `CAP_SYS_NICE` или правами root.

С распределением памяти всё это ни как не связано.

#### Пример

Для примера, есть два процесса, которые выполняют сложные математические расчёты в однопроцессорной системе: `foo` и `bar`, по умолчанию их *уступчивость* равна нулю (ps -l):

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 R  1000 19431 24534  0  80   0 -  5066 -      pts/5    00:10:13 ./foo
0 R  1000 19433 24534  0  80   0 -  3566 -      pts/5    00:11:14 ./bar
```

Как можно видеть они выполняются уже довольно долго (значение потребления процессорного времени в `TIME`). В этот момент мы решаем, что результаты `bar` там важен намного сильнее, чем `foo` и делаем:

```
$ renice 10 -p 19431
```

И примерно через 10 минут ситуация будет следующая:

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
0 R  1000 19431 24534  0  80  10 -  5066 -      pts/5    00:10:55 ./foo
0 R  1000 19433 24534  0  80   0 -  3566 -      pts/5    00:20:03 ./bar
```

т.е. `bar` получил в несколько раз больше времени ЦП; и соответственно должен завершить расчёты намного быстрее.

Answer (score 2):

Команда изменит приоритет процесса с указанным PID с его текущего значения до 10.

В Linux используется система приоритетов из 40 уровней: от -20 (высший приоритет) до 19 (низший приоритет). При этом процессы, запущенные пользователями, как правило, имеют приоритет равный 0. Приоритет процесса используется планировщиком при распределении процессорного времени между процессами, с потреблением памяти это никак не связано.

Это значит, что когда в системе есть несколько процессов, то процессы с высокими приоритетами будут получать больше процессорного времени и, следовательно, будут выполняться быстрее.

Следовательно, если вы измените приоритет процесса с 0 до 10, то соответственно ему будет выделяться меньше процессорного времени и время его выполнения может увеличиться.